# Find the rows and columns of a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, flowlayoutpanel

Just wondering if there is a way to easily lookup the rows and columns currently in a FlowLayoutPanel or if a manual calculation is required?

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel has no columns or rows... Do you mean a TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: No I am using a flow layout panel and adding controls of all the same size and they come up in rows and columns. The controls I am adding are custom controls with a picturebox and label, but the bounding box is just a square and they are all the same size.

Comment: Ah, ok, the child controls in the FlowLayoutPanel appear to be rows and columns but the panel is arranging them from left to right, top to bottom. You'll need to do manual calculation...

Comment: If the control items inside the FlowLayoutPanel are all the same size you could just grab the Y position of the last item added and divide it by the item height (with its margin).

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old yet I had the requirement just today and GetFlowBreak was failing to return true on a control that caused the flow panel to break onto a new line.  I am not sure why and I didn't have time to figure it out.  This works for FlowDirection = LeftToRight.

Frankly, I don't have time to write this but I am anyway.  Here is a simple extension method that will calculate the number of rows:

```
    public static int GetRowCount(this FlowLayoutPanel flowPanel)
    {
        int rows = 1;

        int rowWidth = flowPanel.ClientRectangle.Width;

        foreach (Control control in flowPanel.Controls)
        {
            rowWidth -= control.Width;

            if (rowWidth > 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            rows += 1;
            rowWidth = flowPanel.ClientRectangle.Width;
        }

        return rows;
    }
```

Use:

```
    int rows = ChoiceFlow.GetRowCount();
```

HTH!

CT

Answer (score 0):

The above example was not working for me. It never gave the correct number of rows depending on the `FlowLayoutPanel` size..

So I updated the solution above. Assuming, that all controls in the `FlowLayoutPanel` have same size:

```
    FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    private int GetRowCount()
    {
        int rows;

        int Col = (flp.ClientRectangle.Width - flp.Padding.Left - flp.Padding.Right) / (flp.Controls[0].Width  + flp.Controls[0].Margin.Left + flp.Controls[0].Margin.Right);
        rows = flp.Controls.Count / Col;
        if (flp.Controls.Count % Col != 0)
            rows += 1;
        return rows;
    }

    private int GetFlowHeight()
    {
        if (flp.Controls.Count == 0)
            return 0;

        int h = ((flp.Controls[0].Height + flp.Controls[0].Margin.Top + flp.Controls[0].Margin.Bottom) * GetRowCount()) + flp.Padding.Top + flp.Padding.Bottom;
        return h;
    }
```

In the case of same controls, you don't need to iterate through the controls with this method

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple way to determine this. You have to account for margins and padding. I just happened to be using a margin of 2 and padding of 0, so I used a smaller left location value. Any controls with that small value for the X location will be next to the left of the flowlayout panel. If you wanted to count the number of controls at the top just check the Y location value instead.

```
public int GetRowCount(FlowLayoutPanel flowPanel)
{
    int rows = 0;

    foreach (Control cntrl in flowPanel.Controls)
    {
        if (cntrl.Location.X < 2) // Allow for a small margin or padding
        {
            rows += 1;
        }
    }

    return rows;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example using linq to calculate the height:

```
var heightNeeded = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Control>()
    .Max(x => x.Location.Y + x.Height) + 7;
```