# flowlayputpanel columns and rows

Tags: c#, winforms

How to find how many columns and rows arranged by flowlayoutpanel.

```
FlowLayoutPanel panelstandard = new FlowLayoutPanel();
panelstandard.Size = new Size(1130,150);
panelstandard.Location = new Point(20, 250);
panelstandard.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
panelstandard.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561954/find-the-rows-and-columns-of-a-flowlayoutpanel) but not very helpful.. You could try to enumerate `Controls` and get their location, if `Top` changes -> new row started (but there are `Margin`, `Dock` and `Padding` to check too).

Comment: if i used this for checkbox....then can i find at which checkbox the new row is starting.

Answer (score 0):

You can count it yourself:

```
int row = 0;
int column = -1;
int left = panelstandard.Controls[0].Left;
foreach(Control control in panelstandard.Controls)
{
    // as soon as wrap occurs
    if(control.Left < left)
    {
        // new row
        row++;
        column = 0;
    }
    else
        column++;
    left = control.Left + control.Width; // next control expected left

    // here you know [row; column] of the control
}

// here you know total rows and columns
```

This doesn't take care about control `Margin` and possibly will not work if you use `Dock` and/or `Anchor`, but should work in the general case